# Secret Santa Probability Question

Tags: probability, expectation

In a Secret Santa game, a group of N friends each write their name on a slip of paper and place these slips in a bowl. The slips are mixed and each person draws a slip from the bowl. If anyone draws their own name then the whole process is repeated until each person draws some other person's name. Now that each person has another person's name, this is the name of the recipient of a gift from their Secret Santa. What is the probability that this process can be effected in 3 or fewer tries? Lex $X_i=1$ if person i does not draw their own name and $X_i=0$ if person i does draw their name. Do this for each $i=1,2,...,N$. What is $E[X]$? What is $E[X_1X_2]$? What is $E[X_1+...+X_N]$ for large N (i.e. as N goes to inf)?

It may help to envision this process as a random directed graph. This is a graph with a finite vertex set V. There is also a collection of arrows that is a subset of V x V. IIf (u,v) is in this subset then we draw an arrow from vertex u to vertex v. Notice that the rules imply that every vertex has an arrow departing from it and each vertex has an arrow pointing toward it. Use this representation to prove what the probability is.

I honestly have no idea where to star with this or what I'm even supposed to do... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: omg 1/e i watched it in a video

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  You are picking a random permutation and success is when you get a [derangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).  The chance of that is essentially $\frac 1e$

Comment: Wait, so using derangement I can say that $!n = [\frac{n!}e]$? And does that mean that the expected value is $E[X]=\frac{!n}{n!}$ But what would $E[X_1X_2]$ be? Like how do I determine the value for each X?

Comment: That gives you the probability that you need to draw again.  $E[X_1]$ is just the probability that the first person does not draw their own name.  Can you calculate that?By symmetry, $E[X_i]$ is the same for all $i$ because you can just imagine reordering the drawing. $E[X_1X_2]$ is the chance that neither of the first two drew their own name.  Can you calculate that?  For the last, use the linearity of expectation.

Comment: Wait, why would it be the probability you need to draw again if !n is the number of ways in which they don't draw their own name and thus wouldn't need to draw again? And I don't really get how to do $E[X_i]$...

Comment: as $\frac 1e$ of the permutations are derangements, you draw again with chance $1-\frac 1e$.  When the first person draws, (we are not talking about acceptable draws, but all draws), the chance of getting his own name is $\frac 1n$, so $E[X_1]=\frac 1n$

Comment: So if $E[X_1]=\frac{1}n$, what is the part of the problem that "$X_i=1$ if a person doesn't draw their name and $X_i=0$ if they do?

Comment: By symmetry, all the $E[X_i]$ are equal.  The people could draw in any order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19401/discussion-between-bryyo-357-and-ross-millikan).